# Is there any way to make Postman default to opening saved requests in new tabs

Tags: tabs, postman

I know from the [Postman docs](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/tabs) that I can open saved requests in a new tab either by creating a new tab before clicking on the saved request or with a keyboard shortcut, but I'm hoping there's a way to default Postman to always open requests in new tabs - like the standard functionality of most IDEs.

I frequently find that I've sent a request, then a second, different one and wish I could check something in the response for the first request, but it's no longer there, because the second request opened over the first.

Obviously if I know that I'm going to want the first response, I can explicitly save it, but that's quite cumbersome, and it's usually only after I've sent the next request that I realise I want to refer back.

I suspect the answer is probably to build muscle memory to always hold `Ctrl + Shift` when clicking a saved request, but it would be nice if there was a setting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just realised that this is now possible (or perhaps always was and I just missed it) - in the 'General' tab of the Settings dialog, under the heading 'REQUEST' is a switch for 'Always open requests in new tab'.

Answer (score 10):

There is a setting for this. This image will help:

[image]

Comment: It's incredible that this isn't the default. What a supremely annoying default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As usual mac goes in it's own way and have the same item in the settings, but with a different name.
Same place, but name is "Always open sidebar item in the new tab".

Comment: I cannot find this in the settings at all anymore. Ironically, I want to turn it OFF since I hate having a sluggish app every third day when I realize I have 200 tabs open....

Answer (score -1):

What I found out is that this setting is now called: "Always open sidebar item in tab". I had 100 tabs open until I found out that is the reason for slowness when switching between requests. So when having it open new tab is not a good thing in the long run.